# CakePHP adding data with hasMany relation without form

Tags: forms, cakephp

I have relation: Post hasMany SomeModel

Post has fields: id, title, text
SomeModel has fields: id, unique_name

I create form:

```
echo $form->create('Post');  
echo $form->input('title');  
echo $form->input('text');  
echo $form->end();
```

How to save relations with data like this:

```
$data['Post']['title'] = 'Lorem' // from form  
$data['Post']['text'] = 'Ipsum' // from form  
$data['SomeModel']['unique_name'] = 'generating_unique_name_in_SomeModel'`
```

I try add `$this->data['SomeModel']['unique_name']` in beforeSave in SomeModel, but doesn't work in saveAll in PostController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$data['Post']['title'] = 'Lorem' // from form
$data['Post']['text'] = 'Ipsum' // from form
$data['SomeModel'][0]['unique_name'] = 'generating_unique_name_in_SomeModel'
```

What ever you've written will work fine for `hasOne` relationship. `hasMany` indicates many records so it should be in array notations.